# What is `#override` in .Xresources?

Tags: x11, x-resources

I haven't used .Xresources much, but in the docs that I have looked over, from time to time I see mention of the `#override` command. Or modifier. Or whatever it is.

That's the problem; I don't know what it is (:

Here's an example, taken from `man xterm` on my system:

```
*VT100*translations:    #override \n\
        Meta <KeyPress> /:dabbrev-expand()
```

I've spent a surprising amount of time trying to find out what exactly `#override` is, but with no luck so far.

Can someone point me to docs that explain `#override`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://menehune.opt.wfu.edu/Kokua/Irix_6.5.21_doc_cd/usr/share/Insight/library/SGI_bookshelves/SGI_Developer/books/XLib_WinSys/sgi_html/ch08.html

`#override` merges the translations with the existing translation, overriding any that conflict, compared to `#augment` which also merges, but the existing translations that conflict take precedence.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. I'm still not sure what the exact link is between .Xresources and the described translation tables, but I suspect if I read more of that book I can figure it out...

Comment: @jwd The `translations` resource is a translation from input events (key or mouse presses) to actions (something that happens in a program). In other words, they're key bindings. X resources specify parameters of a program, especially parameters related to the user interface such as visual appearance, or here user input.